# AWS lambda and IAM Network policy

Tags: kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm deploying a lambda function - `StatusCheck` in my VPC. The function is deployed using awscli from one of the pods running on the worker nodes in my k8s cluster. I attach the `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` policy to the k8s worker nodes and the policy looks like

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Clearly by default it will also allow other pods in the k8s cluster to create/delete Network interfaces which is not desirable.

Updating the above policy to add the resource doesn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:77777777:function:*StatusCheck*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error :
`StatusCheck.   Create Failed.   Resource handler returned message: "The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2 (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400`

Is it possible to restrict the create/Delete the ENIs only to the lambda function `StatusCheck` ?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html

Comment: That's the IAM policy that needs to be applied to the Lambda function, so that the function can run correctly inside a VPC. That's not the IAM policy you need to create a Lambda function. The policy needed to create a Lambda function is listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html). Also you aren't using `Resource` correctly at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your policy is that the actions you have specified do not work on a Lambda function resource. They are used by the Lambda to make calls to other services (and there for other, non-Lambda resources).

Looking at the `CreateNetworkInterface` entry on the [IAM actions for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) page (which you're getting the error for) shows that it targets  *network interfaces* and *subnets* (and optionally security groups), so you would need to craft multiple resource names (with wildcards, like you tried) to match those resources if you wanted to limit it to a subset of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when using AWS SAM. I had to add "ec2:DescribeInstances" permissions as well.
So my complete policy is:

```
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
              ]
            Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"

          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: 
              [
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
              ]
            Resource: "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:*"
```